# How to Clear the textfield when any key is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a textfield in my application with some text already in it. I want to clear that text as soon as i press first key. I tried to use keyListener but it is deleting text every single type i press any key. So is there any way, with which, I can clear initial text on only first keypress?

Comment: Can you share part of code you are trying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you looking for [Text Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/).